# Natural phenomena with cubic behaviour

Tags: non-linear-systems, big-list

I'd like to know which natural phenomena (in planet earth) may be described with a cubic function/polynomial? or is there not any.

Accelerated movement is quadratic. Work, is also quadratic. the movement of a spring is trigonometric. radioactive decay is exponatial, etc... which is cubic?

Or put in another way, please refresh me on which SI-Units contain a variable cubic power of the elementary units (m, kg, s, C, ...)

Answer (score 2):

The first few that come to mind are...

Any volume density (of mass, energy, etc.) involves a length cubed.

Kepler’s Third Law relates the square of the period of an orbit to the cube of its semimajor axis.

The low-frequency limit of Planck’s Law for blackbody radiation is cubic in the frequency.

The evaporation time of a black hole due to Hawking radiation is proportional to the cube of its mass.

Comment: Great! thank you! Those are great hints!  Now, do you happen to know of any I can explain to a highschool student? (:

Comment: Any high-school student can understand what a mass density is, and what the period and semimajor axis of a planetary orbit are.

Comment: eventhough the question is on hold, you really got what I meant. could you add some exapmles of volume-density-changing-phenomena?